# Как сделать семантический анализ реплики человека в чате на позитив/негатив?

Tags: c#, текст, бот

Я делаю текстового бота, который должен понимать смысловой тон ответа человека - позитив или негатив, да или нет - и на основе этого выбирать подходящий ответ.

Я подумал, что могу использовать поиск по ключевые фразам, например, вот список "позитивных" фраз:

> "да", "прав", "согласна", "спасибо", "благодарю", "можно", "возможно",
>   "спасибі", "норм", "хорошо", "не плохо", "не погано", "гарно", "ок",
>   "окей", "добре", "давай", "ага", "угу", "буду", "спс", "сенк", "сэнк",
>   "идёт", "идет", "привет", "привіт", "я тоже", "не против", "можливо",
>   "наверное", "может быть", "то да", "это да", "мабуть", "звісно",
>   "конечно", "совершенно верно", "верно", "приятно", "не откажусь", "как
>   и я", "вау", "гоу", "отличная", "не плохая", "хорошая"

Но тут есть несколько проблем. Сложно предугадать все возможные варианты и склонения слова, чтобы включить их в список. А если человек отвечает длинной фразой

> хорошая идея, но на этой неделе я улетел в Египет

то алгоритм вернет совпадение, хотя фраза по сути негативная.

Еще пример:

> давай попрощаемся

тоже даст ложно-позитивный результат.

Есть еще вариант использовать библиотеку типа Lingvo.Net для генерации всех возможных склонений и вариантов каждого слова, но ведь далеко не во всех формах то же самое слово будет задавать тот же оттенок, к тому же слова еще могут иметь разные префиксы, про которые библиотека не знает.

Есть ли какие-то способы по лучше?

Comment: ууу, а сколько выражений в русском языке, имеющих не тот смысл, что выражается в словах)))

Comment: Вот готовый пример на ML.net https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning-samples/tree/master/samples/csharp/getting-started/BinaryClassification_SentimentAnalysis

Comment: @SultanovShamil, но его надо обучать. А у меня нет большой выборки для обучения.